# How can I display a variable value in multiple places within my HTML <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

How do I return a variable value (test) in multiple places in my HTML `<p>` tag.

The variable displays correctly in the first instance but is blank in the second.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
var name = document.querySelector("#NameInput").value;

function fillData() {
  document.querySelector("#nameOutput").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<p>I understand your name is <span><output id="name"></output></span>.</p>
<p>It's nice to meet you `your text`<span><output id="name"></output></span>.</p>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions properly before you submit them. This was unreadable before I edited it

Comment: Regarding your question, the code doesn't appear to work at all - you have no `#nameInput` or `#nameOutput` elements, and `fillData()` isn't called anywhere.. More clarity is required here.

Comment: Tangential: IDs should be unique in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, Rory.  New to this and will be more detailed in future requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs should be unique. Also, the id "nameOutput" does not exist in your HTML code.

Here's a quick solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Variable Output Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Variable Output Example</h1>

    <label for="NameInput">Enter your name:</label>
    <input id="NameInput" type="text">

    <button onclick="fillData()">Submit</button>
    <p>I understand your name is <span><output id="nameOutput1"></output></span>.</p>
    <p>It's nice to meet you, <span><output id="nameOutput2"></output></span>.</p>

    <script>
        function fillData() {
            var name = document.querySelector("#NameInput").value;
            document.querySelector("#nameOutput1").innerHTML = name;
            document.querySelector("#nameOutput2").innerHTML = name;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you.